# Apple Select iPhone process like script/frontend

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, frontend

I'm fairly new to web development (but rapidly learning!). I'm trying to build a selection process just like the one found on Apple's "Shop iPhone" page (http://store.apple.com/us/buy-iphone/iphone5s). Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I'm sure there is a name for this but my search on Google and here on Stackoverflow have returned no result.

Would one use jQuery or Ajax to mimic this? Is there a simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is definitely the way to go, but there isn't anything pre-packaged or out of the box that will get you going.

The best place to start is to begin learning the way jQuery works to manipulate the DOM in order to change the properties and styles that appear on the page.

Some places to get you started:

- http://try.jquery.com/
- http://learn.jquery.com/
- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/
- http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery

And a great tool for playing around:

- http://jsFiddle.net